# NuxtLinks trailing slash anomaly

Tags: nuxt.js

I have an odd situation going on with my links after I generate my static site with Nuxt.

My links are set up on my homepage like this:

```
<NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'review-slug', params: { slug: review.slug } }">
```

In `nuxt.config.js` my router is set to `trailingSlash: false`, which is what I want.
When I use `npm run dev`, everything works fine. All the links on my homepage work correctly and you can click around the site with no problem.

After I generate the site with `npm run generate` and then access these static pages with `npm run start` that is when the problems start.

If you visit a page directly it works as intended, i.e.

- `review/foobar` will bring back the page
- `review/foobar/` will not be found

But from the homepage clicking through to `review/foobar` brings back an empty page (just menu and footer, no content). But if you hit refresh, the page redirects to `review/foobar/` and the page appears.

It is like the slash false rule is being applied for direct urls but the opposite applies for internal links.

Can anyone help? Do I have to do something to configure my `NuxtLink`s for no slash?

Comment: Hm, do you have any error when the page is blank? Also, what happens if you host it on Netlify or Vercel for testing purposes?

Comment: Thanks. I've figured it out - it wasn't an issue with routing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out not to be a routing problem at all. The problem was that the content for these pages relied on a component's `fetch()` method and the output of that fetch was not displaying. I needed to set `fetchonserver: false` on the component to get it to work.